# What should I include to throw bad_function_call exception?

Tags: c++, exception, std

Question in topic.
I tried this:

```
throw new std::bad_function_call("!");
```

got next error:

> error C2039: 'bad_function_call' : is not a member of 'std'
>
> error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'bad_function_call'

Comment: -1: What prevented you from simply Googling this and finding out from the documentation?

Comment: [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bad_function_call).  Took me 3 seconds to find the answer.

Comment: Sorry, just looking at cplusplus.com =( will note that

Comment: [cplusplus.com says the same thing](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bad_function_call/)

Comment: cplusplus.com sucks.  Don't use it.  You never know if what you're reading is the truth or an ugly lie.

Comment: @JohnDibling and more importantly, you cannot fix it if it is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This is new in C++11, and comes from the header `<functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bad_function_call). Include that and pray you have a new enough compiler.

By the way, you should not dynamically allocate exceptions. It's:

- pointless,
- risky for memory allocation exceptions, and
- liable to make your catch sites more complicated than they need to be.

Memory is typically set aside for storing exception objects that are thrown directly, so make use of it. Just write:

```
throw std::bad_function_call("!");
```